# Entity Framework serialization in WebApi not eager-loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using EF 6 and WebApi 2 to serialize entities out to JSON via JSON.Net (AKA Newtonsoft).

Everything works fine as long as I don't have a nested object. The second I do it goes haywire and tries to pull back every single child object.

I'm using eager loading (`LazyLoadingEnabled = false`) and I've got a query similar to this:

```
return db.Users.Include(user => user.Department).Take(10);
```

However, the serialization of those results ended up in a cyclic reference. Even though I didn't tell it too it pulls the entire object graph as if it was lazy-loaded which of course is all sorts of bad.

For example, it tries to serialize out:

```
user.Department.Employees
user.Department.Managers
user.Department.Positions
```

Which is of course bad because those are users...which have departments...which have users... and ends up in the obvious circular reference loop.

If I use the JSON serializer's `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` I end up with it detecting the references and adding `$ref` to the JSON output and outputs the data, but it shouldn't have to in the first place because EF shouldn't have loaded the Employees and Managers collections AND this breaks things on the client side. I tried messing with the `ProxyCreationEnabled` but that makes no difference true or false.

I tried using the JSON serializer's `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` that appears like it's supposed to detect the loop and simply stop serializing at that point but it gets into an infinite loop.

EDIT: Here's my api route:

```
    // GET: api/User
    public IQueryable<User> GetPositions()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return db.Users
            .Include(e => e.Department);
    }
```

And here's the WebApiConfig:

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None; // returns 500 error if "None", returns unwanted data and format if "Objects"
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(json);
```

UPDATE: I did a `ToList` on the results of the query before they end up returned from my api call. EF is loading the child objects before it ever gets to the serializer.

Comment: I have the same frustrations, and I rarely run into a scenario where the reverse reference is ever needed. I don't know why they default to these ungodly cyclicals. What worked for me, on designer mode, is turning off/marking private or internal, the reverse path. On the child /referenced table, there's a relationship back to the parent. Set it private or internal and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: It worked for me when used AutoMapper and MVC models not to use EF objects for serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if I'm understanding correctly this is [expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692730/101197). I believe, after following the link even deeper to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251914/guidance-for-synchronising-reverse-associations-in-entity-framework-4-1/6259284#6259284), I'm confusing things because I'm used to using `ObjectContext` instead of `DbContext`.

I've since pivoted in a different direction for my solution and began flattening my objects before returning from the WebApi with either a View or an anonymous type and using custom `PUT` and `POST` for updating and creating objects.