# Entity Framework 6 Populating Un-Included Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, include

I have a context with `LazyLoadingEnable = false` and `ProxyCreateEnabled=false`.  When submitting queries I explicitly `.Include` what I want.  The issue is that some of the navigation properties are populated even if they where not included.  For example:

```
context.Order.Include(o => o.OrderLines)
```

`OrderLine` has a navigation property back to `Order` that is populated while it was not requested in the include.

I believe I understand *why* this is happening in that the given Order is in context and as a part of relationship fix-up it is populated.

Based on the contents of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251914/guidance-for-synchronising-reverse-associations-in-entity-framework-4-1/), it appears that disabling change tracking should prevent this.  I have tried performing the query with `.AsNotTracking()` and setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` in the context, but these un-included navigation properties are still populated.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it's a good design. It's ridiculous that when `Order` has its `OrderLines` populated but each `OrderLine` does not have any reference back to `Order`. It's done right when the `Include` does its job.

Comment: This is due to the object graph itself. To lazy load the navigation properties use this.yourNavProperty = new Lazy<SomeEntity>(); in the constructor that has the linking to the virtual property.

Comment: I guess I do not understand either of these replies.  I suppose the first is the equivalent of *don't do that*.  I think the second is not addressing the question at all (Unless I am being very dense which could certainly be).

Comment: actually, both replies address your question perfectly. to give you your query results, EF materializes the datarows into the context, which is basically an object graph. when an Order has a link to an OrderLine, it is just expected for the OrderLine to have a link back to the Order. EF is behaving like it was being designed to.

Comment: I understand that is *how* it works.  If you look at the question I linked, it seems like this behavior should not occur if AsNoTracking is added to the query.  It did not seem this was the case for me.