# Why child entites binds to parent automatically in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I don't know this is a good or bad thing and how to adapt this.

Parent-Child has very simple and obvious relation.No big deal. You can see the code below:

#### Parent Object:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Child> Childs {get;set;}
}
```

#### Child Object

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public Parent Parent {get;set;}
}
```

#### Somewhere around the code(say index method of the controller)

```
var parent = parentRepository.FindAll(x=> x.Id == 10).ToList();
var childCollection = childRepository.FindAll(x=> x.ParentId == parent.Id).ToList();
```

When i run the code above i expect a `parent` object with `Childs` Property is `null` and `childCollection` that has null `Parent` property. But this is not happening. After second line of code executed, `parent.Childs` fills with the child objects and every `Parent` property in a child object is equal to `parent` which i don't want it(should i want it?).

Why entityframework behaves like that? And which cases should i be aware off? What happens if i change the `childCollection` without knowing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the normal behavior of EF. At the moment when the `childCollection`  is materialized calling `ToList`, when you check `parent` instance again, relationship fixup will run and check if `Child` entities whose FK have the same value as the PK of your current `parent` have been loaded earlier in the object context. If that is the case, the `Parent.Childs` property will immediately be set with those `Child` entities. This doesn't have nothing to do with lazy loading, in fact your model doesn't meet all the [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) that lazy loading need, like your navigation properties should be `virtual`.

This behavior cannot be disabled but if you use [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method at the time to build your queries, the entities returned will not be cached in the `DbContext`:

```
var query= context.Childs.AsNoTracking().Where(c=>c.ParentId==10);
```

You can also find more details in this excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251914/guidance-for-synchronising-reverse-associations-in-entity-framework-4-1/6259284#6259284)

Comment: Great. I got it. AsNoTrackin() option will save my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like many modern ORMs, Entity Framework is designed not only to map your queries results to entities (objects), but to map their relationships to properties. If you declare a *navigation property* (such as you have done with `Childs` or `Parent` properties in your classes), EF will (lazily) map those properties to their referenced entities automatically (you can find more about navigation properties [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first)).

This behavior is by design and has the intent to avoid explicitly do queries using joins, and makes it unnecessary to call `childRepository.FindAll(x=> ...` because all related `Child` entities are loaded by EF as soon as you access the `Childs` property in your `Parent` object.

Remember also that EF implements a change tracking system, so if you modify entities fetched from the database, EF will track those changes and persists them the first time you call `SaveChanges` on your context.

As a side note, EF architecture is really an example of the UnitOfWork and Repository patterns used together (DbContext is a UoW and each DbSet works like a Repository), so I strongly suggest you to read more about EF to avoid misusing its features or re-implementing them yourself using another abstraction (e.g. your Repositories).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But one question, what do you mean with the re-implementing? Repository pattern is widely used with the entity framework?